# Ubuntu program to access offline Windows Maps

Tags: 18.04, windows, gnome-maps

Is there some Ubuntu program to access or display offline Windows Maps????

Comment: Which Ubuntu program are you currently using to display Windows Maps, whether online or offline?

Comment: Obviously from the question, none! I downloaded most of the world- 15gb so would be real nice. I'm trying to make Ubuntu main dependable system.

Comment: Is "Windows Maps" some kind of application? Or is it a Windows feature?

Comment: Yes, it's an app, but very simple.

Comment: Are you asking how to run a Windows application on Ubuntu? Or are you asking something else? What file format do the map files use? Are you asking which applications can be used to open those files? Your question is still unclear - help us to help you.